# How to check who modified a file on Linux

Tags: linux

We are a big team and occassionally developers directly change a file on dev/ uat server which breaks another thing. Instead of mailing out to entire team asking for who did the change and for what reason, we would like to know who made that change and then directly get to the concerned person.

Is there a way to do this over linux server? I read audit package installed on linux could do that, but I get permissioned denied. Pls suggest if there are alternative ways to deal with this problem.

```
ausearch -f file.txt
Error opening config file (Permission denied)
NOTE - using built-in logs: /var/log/audit/audit.log
Error opening /var/log/audit/audit.log (Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may require sudo permissions to run that command, try running this `sudo ausearch -f file.txt`.